# Returning an object from a Class like mongoose

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongoose

How is `mongoose.js` returning an object from:

```
var silence = new Kitten({
  name: 'Silence'
});

console.log(silence); // { name: 'Silence' }
```

But if you check the source code `Kitten` is a function called `model` on [this code](https://github.com/LearnBoost/mongoose/blob/3.8.x/lib/model.js#L2512) which then points to the document source code [here](https://github.com/LearnBoost/mongoose/blob/3.8.x/lib/document.js#L57).

```
function Document (obj, fields, skipId) {
  this.$__ = new InternalCache;
  this.isNew = true;
  this.errors = undefined;
  //...
  this._doc = this.$__buildDoc(obj, fields, skipId);
  if (obj) {
    this.set(obj, undefined, true);
  }
}
```

Which means it should be returning something like:

```
var silence = new Kitten({
  name: 'Silence'
});

console.log(silence); // { _obj: { name: 'Silence' } }
```

So how is it that they are returnin another object than the constructed class itself?

---

*Further investigation*:

Manually changing the `ret` [here](https://github.com/LearnBoost/mongoose/blob/3.8.x/lib/document.js#L1525) makes the class return that specified ret.